How to change drop down button of select tag to inner-spin-button like <input type = "number"> have
Select Tag Drop Down Buton(https://i.sstatic.net/yEv5G.png) to Inner-spin-button(https://i.sstatic.net/Aoshj.png)
select::-webkit-inner-spin-button{ 
 -webkit-appearance: number;
 appearance: number;
}

I am not get the solution please help me out through the proper solution.
I want to change drop down button to spin button in the Select tag



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Number Input Styling</title>
  <style>
    input[type="number"] {
      height: 32px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 20px;
      width: 80px;
      outline: none;
      background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2050%2067%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%3E%3Cg%20fill%3D%22none%22%20stroke-width%3D%222%22%3E%3Cline%20x1%3D%221%22%20x2%3D%2250%22%20y1%3D%2233.5%22%20y2%3D%2233.5%22%20stroke%3D%22%23D8D8D8%22%2F%3E%3Cpolyline%20transform%3D%22translate(25%2020)%20rotate(45)%20translate(-25%20-20)%22%20points%3D%2219%2026%2019%2014%2032%2014%22%20stroke%3D%22%23000%22%2F%3E%3Cpolyline%20transform%3D%22translate(25%2045)%20rotate(225)%20translate(-25%20-45)%22%20points%3D%2219%2052%2019%2039%2032%2039%22%20stroke%3D%22%23000%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E');
      background-position: center right;
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      caret-color: transparent;
    }
    
    input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
      -webkit-appearance: none !important;
      opacity: 1 !important;
      background: transparent !important;
      border-width: 0px;
      margin: 0;
      border-left: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
      height: 34px;
      width: 23px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <label for="numberInput">Enter a number:</label>
  <input type="number" id="numberInput">
</body>

</html>



My solution is for styling the inner spin buttons of number input fields, while your code is for styling the inner spin buttons of select elements specially in webkit-based browsers. The "appearance" property is used to set a predefined style for certain elements, and in this case, it's setting the appearance to a type of number input spinner. Hope this helps.
